# Scrollstart event not fire while scrolling in jQuery mobile.?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using scrollstart event in jQuery mobile but it is not fire on browser. But it fire on device. My problem is that I need to do task while scrolling I need to give height to div if someone scroll that div.Div take the height but problem is that it goes to top of div content.

Mean I need if user focus should be there after giving the height. Not goes to top of contend.

First I need to fire scroll start function when user scroll the div contends(which is running on Ipad) but not running on browser. Then I give height to div

```
$('div#realTimeContents').css("height", "")
```

Then focus goes to top of the contend.

HERE IS MY FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/x7ZyB/2/

```
$(document).on('scrollstart', '#realTimeContents', function() {
  alert("scroll---");
  isScrolling=false;
  $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", "")
  //$('div#realTimeContents').css("height", null)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You javascript code in your Fiddle has a syntax error, besides that:

1. You are not attaching correctly your event. Try with this once your page is initialized:

   ```
   $('#realTimeContents').on('scrollstart', function () {
     //CODE
   });
   ```
2. You are using a version of jQuery Mobile with some bugs (at least in the Fiddle), use a stable one as 1.3.1.

I have a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pLk4k/).